# Gnome Screenshot sometimes shots an image from the past

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, swap, plymouth, gnome-screenshot

When I'm taking screenshots, it sometimes takes a screenshot from several minutes ago. It is not always the case, sometimes it takes few screenshots correctly, and then one from the past few minutes.

The history when this issue started to occur. I wanted to expand my swap partition and I've done it with `gparted` and after that changed `fstab` file. After that I had **recovering journal** issue when system wakes up after **hibernation**. I tried to find what caused this problem, but I couldn't find the way. Some crazy guy on some forum told to reinstall `plymouth`. I was crazy enough and did that even though I didn't know what it was. After that, my laptop couldn't boot into **ubuntu desktop** anymore. After installing ubuntu desktop again, it booted into desktop but with crashed font (fixed that by changing font size in Settings -> Universal Access).

The day after this happened, I started getting this unusual issue with the screenshots. Do you have any idea if I uninstalled something necessary with reinstalling plymouth package?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What did you modify in the `fstab` file? Also, did you run a file system check with `fsck`?

Comment: Thank you. I added the UUID of newly created swap partition, but I didn't run `fsck`.  Should I run it on all pratitions or just on swap?

Comment: `sudo touch /forcefsck` then reboot. :)

Comment: this did not fix the problem. I am getting **recovering journal** error on system startup when I wake up from hibernate and it fails to recover opened programs.

Comment: Hibernate? We're we talking about that? I didn't notice from the question. By the way please post the full error message and the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: excuse me, I didn't mention that **recovering journal (cleaning orphaned inode)** appear every time on startup after hibernating (hibernate fails). Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo lsblk` and `free -m` (and also the contents of `/etc/fstab`).

Comment: maybe related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=216500